# What's special about the chosen people?

Tags: orthodox

Why are Jews called the chosen people?  What makes them special and different from everybody else?

Comment: "Why are people called 'orthodox Jews' calling themselves the chosen ones?" Citation? I've never heard of this.

Comment: Can you perhaps reword your question to be less harsh and offensive?  You might get fewer downvotes if you were asking a question and not making an accusation.

Answer (score 2):

The term "chosen people" isn't something that orthodox Jews invented to label themselves, it is a textual reference to a status conferred by the divine (if one accepts the authority of the text in question). Why do Americans call America "the home of the brave"? Because there is a poem which uses that phrase about America and Americans see that poem as an accurate and authoritative statement about themselves.

Does this mean that America is "special" or just that Americans see it as having a particular position in their lives and their world view?

The term "chosen" seems to offend some people. And yet it doesn't mean "special" any more than a student who is "chosen" to go to an Ivy League college is "special" while someone going to any other school isn't. Or someone who feels a calling to go into politics vs. someone who stumbles into a life as a lawyer.

Comment: Thanks, it's only your personal view, or you can back it up with some proof from a holy book or something similar?

Comment: any proof from a faith based text would not be helpful if you don't see authority in the text. I could quote deut 7:7-8 but what good would that do?

Comment: Can you quote that?

Comment: yes, I can. לֹא מֵרֻבְּכֶם מִכָּל הָעַמִּים חָשַׁק יְהֹוָה בָּכֶם וַיִּבְחַר בָּכֶם כִּי אַתֶּם הַמְעַט מִכָּל הָעַמִּים

Comment: @Danno: Your answer isn't just for Derfder, but for everyone else who finds this while searching on the internet. If you feel you have something that will improve the answer, add it into the answer, even if you feel the asker won't accept it

Answer (score 0):

noone is more "special" than anyone else. some people have different jobs to do. if a nonjew does what he's supposed to do, he's considered among the righteous of the nations and has completely fulfilled his purpose.

this audio explains it much better than i could. Three flaws of Man - the role of the Jews. by Rabbi Uziel Milevsky O.B.M. former chief rabbi of mexico

http://dafyomireview.com/audio/m04-3_flaws_of_man_and_role_of_jews.mp3

Comment: Please, provide some evidence